# How to pass request params to resttemplate in post request with xml - body?

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I try to write integration tests for spring-application controllers.

So, this controller can receive post - request with xml in body and with params in url.

I tried to use restTemplate like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        params.add("city", "London");
        params.add("street", "backer");
        params.add("house", "1");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(user, headers);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                String.format("%s/user", getServerAddress()),
                entity,
                Object.class,
                params
        );
```

So, user - xml mapped in object.

There is error message in this case - 400 null from server.

But if I remove params from restTemplate params and and my params in url after "?" - no errors will thrown.

How to pass params to rest template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a String representation of your XML using jaxb and send the string as request body.
I consider you have an object representation of your request body `yourCusomObject`
Using `jaxbMarshaller` you can convert your object to and xml in String.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(yourCusomObject, sw);
String objectAsXmlString = sw.toString();

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(objectAsXmlString, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("/url", entity, String.class);
```

---

*OP also wants to know how to pass query parameters*

`http://MyHost:PORT/employee/{employee_id}`

Consider this is my url which has a path variable `employee_id` and I also need to add query parameter (`?firstName=Abc&lastName=Pqr`) to the url

Here is is how you should do it. 
Code gives an URI instance which can be used in restTemplate.

```
       String url = "http://MyHost:PORT/employee/{employee_id}";

        Map<String, String> uriParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uriParams.put("employee_id", "1231231");

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
                // Add query parameter
                .queryParam("firstName", "Abc")
                .queryParam("lastName", "Pqr");

        URI urlWithParameters = builder.buildAndExpand(uriParams).toUri();
```

> However, avoid using query parameters with POST

Comment: It's okey, but how to pass url params with restTemplate? In url params after "?" I expected to pass compare key for writing to database.

Comment: you are talking about two different things here. One is sending XML as request body (which I answered here)
Second is passing query parameters in post request for that I am adding second part to my answer